# Apollo Upload memory leakage on large upload

Tags: node.js, performance, apollo, apollo-server

I have an express server to upload files. When I upload a large amount of files during one post I get the following message:

```
MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 SIGINT 
listeners added to [process]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
```

How might I be able to fix this? I would like to allow uploads with large amount of files at a single time.

I have the following mutation

```
    uploadFiles(
      files: [Upload]
    ): Boolean
```

My resolver is

```
await Promise.all(
        files.map(async (file: any) => {
          const { createReadStream, filename, mimetype } = await file;
          return new Promise(res =>
            createReadStream()
              .pipe(createWriteStream(`${process.env.DESTINATION}/${filename}`))
              .on("close", res),
          ).catch(err => console.log("err saving: ", err));
        }),
      );
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure your Promise is rejected if an error occurs while writing the file:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
  createReadStream()
    .pipe(createWriteStream(`${process.env.DESTINATION}/${filename}`))
    .on('close', resolve),
    .on('error', reject)
)
```